# It is equivalent to consider an algebra A over a field F and A over the prime subfield of F?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory

I'm studying the proof of the Amitsur-Levitzki theorem by the book "Introduction to Noncommutative Algebra" of Matej Bresar and the theorem affirms that the standard polynomial $s_{2n}$ is an identity of $M_n(C)$ for every commutative algebra C. But in the proof the autor begin considering an algebra over some field F but then it changes and starts to consider C as an algebra over $F_0$, the prime subfield of $F$, why can I do that? Those two things are equivalent?